# $event.keyCode добавление символа

Tags: javascript, angularjs

может ктото сталкивался с похожей проблемой. Мне нужно добавить символ è в $event.keyCode. Возможно ли добавление или расширение базы этого события? Зарание спасибо!

Comment: $event.key пробовали?

Comment: еще нет, сейчас попробую, спасибо